# When the request delegate gets called?

Tags: owin, asp.net-core

In ASP.NET 5 the `Configure` method from the `Startup` class is responsible for configuring the pipeline with the `IApplicationBuilder` functionality. This interface provides then one `Build` method that picks all middlewares added and gives back one `RequestDelegate` that includes all the functionality of the pipeline and is able to deal with requests.

Now, when this delegate gets called? I imagine that once a request is received, the server layer will build one `HttpContext` out of the raw HTTP message and then pass it into the `RequestDelegate` built by the `IApplicationBuilder`. Is that really the case?

If so, on ASP.NET 5 source code, where's the code that does this job of really handling the requests? Or is this a job for the server, like IIS or WebListener and Kestrel?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that about sums it up. Requests arrive via IIS/WebListener/Kestrel and are passed up to Hosting. Hosting creates an HttpContext and then executes the RequestDelegate.

Look here for details:
https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting/Internal/HostingEngine.cs#L69-L80